# Recoding values in a selection of columns of a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

I have a large dataset like the one in the next example. Columns with As in their headers have codes from 1 to 4, and columns with Bs from 1 to 3.

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(
     ID = 1:10,
     A = sample(x = 1:4, size = 10, replace = T),
     AA = sample(x = 1:4, size = 10, replace = T),
     B = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = T),
     BB = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = T)
)
```

[image]

Is there a neat way to use pipes in dplyr to recode the values from columns with As in the headers and columns with Bs to the following strings?

- As - from 1, 2, 3, 4 to Green, Yellow, Orange, Red respectively
- Bs - from 1, 2, 3 to Green, Yellow, Red respectively

This is a simplified and friendlier version of the real dataset.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using mutate_at from dplyr, it is possible to accomplish the recodification from numeric codes to strings. It is necessary to first coerce the columns we want to recode from numeric to character or, otherwise, there will be an error message.

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(
     ID = 1:10,
     A  = sample(x = 1:4, size = 10, replace = T),
     AA = sample(x = 1:4, size = 10, replace = T),
     B  = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = T),
     BB = sample(x = 1:3, size = 10, replace = T))

d_recoded <- d %>% mutate_at(vars(-contains("ID")), funs(as.character)) %>%
             mutate_at(vars(contains("A"), -contains("ID")), funs(case_when(. == 1 ~ "Green", . == 2 ~ "Yellow", . == 3 ~ "Orange", . == 4 ~ "Red"))) %>%
             mutate_at(vars(contains("B"), -contains("ID")), funs(case_when(. == 1 ~ "Green", . == 2 ~ "Yellow", . == 3 ~ "Red")))
```